# axios-cache-adapter vs redis for caching api responses

Tags: express

I need to implement caching to save API calls response data, to only fetch from API if it is a new request. I found [axios-cache-adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-cache-adapter) and ioredis, but I really don't know what would be the pros and cons of using which one